# Can I get the type of clamps that are utilized by the Peak DCA55 Semiconductor analyzer for a multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, adapter, plug

I love how on my DCA55 it has push button with clamps that I can use to clamp down on the component I'm testing. Is there a place I might find this attachment for my multimeter? Also, what are the names of the plugs/and,or attachments that go to a multimeter named? (I heard the name banana plug while Googling, is this correct?)

Comment: Please add a photo of the clamp that you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are typically called "Minigrabbers" and yes, the end for most multimeters are banana plugs. Here's an example of what you want: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/4650-24-2/501-1326-ND/736917